# Bounty refund after question migrated from MSE to MSO - is this expected behavior?

Tags: support, bounties, migration, migrated-questions, mso-mse-split

Right before split, I [offered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/227454/revisions) bounty on this question:

- [Stack Overflow is not yet a vast wasteland: a history of moderator tooling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling)

During split, above question has been moved to MSE, where bounty was rewarded.

Recently, question was [migrated to MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250976/839601). After migration, I discovered that my bounty was refunded.

Is this expected behavior? What would happen if later the question migrates back to MSE?

> <sub>Not that I complain, :) just curious (FWIW I wouldn't mind if refund is rolled back either).</sub>

Comment: I would think that would be expected behavior on a question when it gets migrated as the person offering the bounty might not have the ability to offer it on the site it was moved to.