# Are there any exceptions to "reputation for a bounty is irreversibly deducted from your reputation"?

Tags: support, bounties

Here is an excerpt from the [Help pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), to answer the question "**What happens when I place a bounty?**":

> The reputation you're using for the bounty is immediately and irreversibly deducted from your reputation.

Are there any exceptions to this rule? I.e. situations/actions where the bounty award is "returned" to the user who issued the bounty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **YES**, there is at least 1 such situation: **When a question with an open bounty is put on hold**.

For a real world illustration of it, refer to what happened in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164463/recommendations-to-get-started-with-drupal-and-grow):

- around the time of the comment from [kiamlaluno](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno), this question also received "on hold" status.
- at the very same moment, [Herci's reputation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/34116/herci?tab=reputation) increased with +50 again (good for Herci).
- AND the bounty that was related to this question ([issued by Herci on July 12](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/34116/herci?tab=reputation)) disappeared (no longer shows up anywhere on this question), though the bounty wasn't expired or granted to any answer yet.

And if you think you understand it all, then have a look at the timelines of these questions (I never received any info about the removal of BOTH bounties, on Jan 31 between 17:43 and 17:44):

- [Are there any alternatives to applying for a full project on drupal.org?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/176531/are-there-any-alternatives-to-applying-for-a-full-project-on-drupal-org).
- [How to implement a multi step approval with webforms/entityforms based on form components?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164601/how-to-implement-a-multi-step-approval-with-webforms-entityforms-based-on-form-c)

Here are some more answers to further illustrate/document all this:

- The answer (sub-bullet) about "*Can I offer a second bounty after the first one has expired?*", within the answer about [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067), which states:

  > Bounty questions cannot be closed directly.
  >
  > However, [diamond moderators][3] can refund bounties, which would then allow it to be closed, migrated, or deleted like any other question
- [How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103)

Would be nice if some day that "irreversibly" part in the [Help pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) would be corrected to reflect this.

Comment: Although they can, isn't it also exceptional? And with that, should it be part of the help? There are other rules that can change with moderator or CM intervention.

Comment: Well, even though "exceptional" might be true, I find "irreversible" misleading (to not just say "incorrect")... Moreover, a variation of this could be "what if the bounty was already granted to "an" answer (not sure what will happen in that case, and haven't done any help research yet).

Comment: If the bounty was already granted to an answer, then the bounty is done and a moderator cannot refund the amount of the bounty. They don't need to, since the question is not blocked from closure by the bounty any longer.

Comment: Yes, it's true that moderators can refund them, but the point of the wording is that users should have absolutely **no** expectation that they can get a bounty refunded if they ask for it to be refunded. This ability is only provided so that they can close questions. We don't want to explain the exceptions to users because most users simply don't need to know any exceptions exist.

Comment: OK, makes sense, but something like that "...  users should have absolutely no expectation that they can get a bounty refunded if they ask for it to be refunded ..." would seem more appropriate to me (instead of the "irreversibly"). Think about users who did post an answer, and put some special effort in it, because of the "hm, let me try to get that bounty" ... And then all of a sudden the bounty disappears ... They might think "if I would have known that the question was going to be put on hold, I'd not have wasted my time on answering".

Comment: Don't put special effort in to answering off-topic questions, even if they have a bounty.

Comment: @BilltheLizard : I agree, but IMHO it was not off-topic .. Which I believe is somehow confirmed by the number of upvotes of my answer there also,. Isn't upvoting (a lot) some kind of indication that it is perceived by many users as not off-topic?

Comment: No, upvoting is unlocked at 15 reputation. Almost anyone can do it. Upvotes are not any indication that a question is on-topic.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: To reinforce what Bill said (not that he needs it...) contrast 15 rep upvoting with 3k rep to cast reopen votes.

Comment: OK thanks for your feedback from both. I see your points, though it reminds me that I find it really hard to predict if some question is going to be off topic or not. Things like faqs etc aren't really clear on that IMHO ... Moreover it would be nice if The community could somehow decide about what is on-topic or not, so that it could evolve over time also. Anyway"asking questions" (that are on-topic) seems like an art. to me ...

Comment: bounties are also refunded for migrated questions when migration stub gets deleted at source site, see eg [Already awarded bounty refunded on question migration?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140184/165773)

Comment: @gnat : interesting, didn't realize/know that. But of course that makes sense somehow. Why don't you add it as a separated question (I'd +1 it ...)?

Comment: I had that [separate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229945/165773) long time ago, turned out duplicate

Comment: Questions with bounties cannot be put on hold. The question has to have the bounty cancelled first (by a moderator), bounty refunded, and then question put on hold. So "When a question with an open bounty is put on hold" is not really an exception to the rule of "when can bounties be refunded", because it cannot be put on hold. The exception is, more specifically, "the bounty is cancelled manually by a moderator for reasons", and "refund" is more a side-effect of the need to cancel the bounty :)